# How to Implement the capture image from Camera as Like take Image from gallery in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, camera

In my application i have Implement to take image from Gallery.
In that gallery is open on the click of button and after selecting the image, that activity is close and selected image is shown to the previous activity ImageView.

As like that, I want to imaplement the Camera preview that captured the image from camera Activity and after taking captured image i come back to my original activity with that captured image.

So how to implement such technique ??
Or is there any demo that take captured image from android camera and come back to original activity with that captured image ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this, what you looking for? (AS I Understand you question)

**In Manafiest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**In your activity**

```
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;

private void takePhoto(){
  final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) ); 
  startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}

private File getTempFile(Context context){
  //it will return /sdcard/image.tmp
  final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
  if(!path.exists()){
    path.mkdir();
  }
  return new File(path, "image.tmp");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch(requestCode){
      case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
        final File file = getTempFile(this);
        try {
          Bitmap captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file) );
          // do whatever you want with the bitmap (Resize, Rename, Add To Gallery, etc)
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for the answer. Let me check.

Comment: Ok Let me see the result. And I have already one Override function like onActivityResult(....) that i use for the Facebook Integration. . . So what more i have to do to implement your code. . ?

Comment: In your onActivityResult put if condition and use switch case for both results (camera and facebook).

Comment: Yup. ..  Ok Let me try it. . . Thanks for help. .